# Cannot resolve all parameters for AppPage in app.page.ts (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, webstorm, tsconfig

Here's the code for my `AppComponent` -- note that I'm calling it `AppPage` because it will evolve into a "smart" component later:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '@app/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slctr-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppPage {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    authService.handleAuthentication();
  }
}
```

In WebStorm, `@Component` is underlined with the following error: `Cannot resolve all parameters for AppPage in app.page.ts (?)`

My `tsconfig.json` file has `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` and `"lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ]` and the app does build correctly.

What am I missing?

Update: Showing `CoreModule` and `AppModule` code:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [LandingPageComponent],
  providers: [
    // App singleton services
    AuthService
  ],
  exports: [
    // 3rd party libraries
    // Components
    LandingPageComponent
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
  // make sure CoreModule is imported only by one NgModule: the AppModule
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('CoreModule is already loaded. Please import it in the AppModule only.');
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppPage]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Update:** Adding `AuthService` code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: environment.auth0.clientId,
    domain: environment.auth0.domain,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: environment.auth0.audience,
    redirectUri: environment.auth0.redirectUri,
    scope: 'openid email profile'
  });

  public static loggedIn(): boolean {
    // Check whether the current time is past the access token's expiry time
    return new Date().getTime() < JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
  }

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize({});
  }

  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        // Set the time that the access token will expire at
        localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime()));
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        // Route to
      } else if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is: `constructor(private router: Router) {}`

Comment: make sure you have @Injectable() decorator for service class and you have added it as a provider in module.

Comment: Both are true really :(

Comment: in tsconfig.json "experimentalDecorators": true?

Comment: Yes, `"experimentalDecorators": true`

Comment: ...and it's also doing it now for `LandingPage` component. Does it have to do with the suffix `Page`?!

Comment: add the definition of the service class

Comment: and maybe change the import path for the service class to a full or relative path

Comment: What does your file structure look like for `import { AuthService } from '@app/core';` to work?

Comment: This works because I have `"@app/*": ["app/*"]` under `"paths"` in `tsconfig.json`. Otherwise the structure is as `angular-cli` made it: `src/app` under which there's a separate folder for each module, except for `app.page.ts`, `app.module.ts`, and `app.routing.ts` that are directly under `app` root. I also have an `index.ts` file in the root folder of each module that exports everything from the sibling files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue that will be fixed in Angular v5.1.0: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16382

**Update, Dec. 7, 2017:** I confirm, this was fixed in v5.1.0